# Удаление элемента из списка Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

Есть объект `ScrollViewer`, содержащий `StackPanel`:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel x:Name="ShopList"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

При нажатии на кнопку `FoodAdd`:

```
<Button 
    x:Name="FoodAdd" 
    Content="Добавить" 
    Margin="287,102,0,17" 
    Height="81"
    Width="130" 
    BorderBrush="#FFFBEFEF" 
    Foreground="#FFFFF7F7" 
    Background="#FF56E0C7" 
    FontFamily="/Assets/Fonts/Stolzl.otf#Stolzl Light" 
    Click="NewItem"/>
```

в `ShopList` добавляется новый объект методом `NewItem`:

```
private void NewItem(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string item_name = NewFood.Text;
    if(item_name.Trim(' ') != "")
    {
        Button new_button = new Button();
        new_button.Content = item_name;
        new_button.Width = 350;
        new_button.HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        new_button.FontSize = 30;
        Thickness thick = new Thickness(0);
        thick.Bottom = 1;
        new_button.BorderThickness = thick;
        new_button.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x4F, 0x4E, 0x4E));
        new_button.Click += Delete_fromlist;
        ShopList.Children.Add(new_button);
    }
    NewFood.Text = "";
    NewFood.Focus(FocusState.Keyboard);
}
```

А удаляется из него методом `Delete_fromlist`:

```
private void Delete_fromlist(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ((Button)sender).Content = "";
    ShopList.Children.Remove(((Button)sender));
}
```

И вот тут образуется проблема. При удалении элемента (= нажатию по нему) всплывает тач-клавиатура телефона. Сам элемент удаляется успешно. С чем это может быть связано?
Спасибо.

Comment: А это `NewFood.Focus(FocusState.Keyboard);` зачем?

Comment: @Bulson После добавления элемента в список, очищаю текстовую строку и переключаю на неё ввод с клавиатуры, чтобы можно было добавлять несколько элементов подряд не тыкая в неё каждый раз)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как выяснилось, при удалении/скрытии элемента (например, `Button`) фокус переключался на соседствующий с ним `TextBox x:Name="NewFood"` (эта проблема достаточно актуальна для WP8.1).

Починил следующим образом:

```
private void Delete_fromlist(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            NewFood.IsTabStop = false;
            ShopList.Children.Remove(((Button)sender));
            NewFood.IsTabStop = true;
        }
```